# Typeface used in Garmin GPS device

Tags: font-identification

Can someone please guide me what typeface is used in [this Garmin GPS device](https://buy.garmin.com/en-CA/CA/p/552113)?

[image: Garmin GPS device screens]

I did some research on this. I believe they are using Frutiger ([as per this link](https://fontmeme.com/images/GarminGuidelines.pdf)) or Open Sans ([as per this link](https://www.garmin.com/en-US)). On their website they have mostly used Open Sans, Roboto, Knockout, and Arial.

I'm a beginner and have zero background in typography. I just took one course on Lynda.com and am reading Prof. Brighurst's book. So, please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Hi watchtower, I edited your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many coincidences, [Prima Sans](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/prima-sans/) from Myfonts.com

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How did you get the code from the Garmin GPS screen?

Comment: All browsers have the option to see the page source code in the menu

Comment: Thanks Danielillo. True. However, I want to know the typeface used on the device and not on their website. I have clarified my question above. My sincere apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you please elaborate how you arrived at this? I want to learn the process. Hope that's okay with you.

Comment: Google search for big size images [like this one](https://brain-images-ssl.cdn.dixons.com/7/0/10162507/u_10162507.jpg) allows to see the font more clearly, and searching for some few key characters: Q, 1, R, K

Answer (score 0):

That font is DejaVu Sans. The font Garmin still uses

Comment: Hello Eero, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Usually, we expect users to substantiate their answer with proof. For example, the other answer by  Daniellillo shows side-by-side comparisons between both fonts. Why do you think it's DejaVu Sans? You can [edit] your answer to add more info.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/115341)